# Excluding missing keys from JSON comparison

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, jestjs

I have two JSON documents that I want to assert equal for Jest unit testing. They should be equal, except the second one has one more key: _id.

Example:

```
doc1.json
{
    username: 'someone',
    firstName: 'some',
    lastName: 'one',
}

doc2.json
{
    _id: '901735013857',
    username: 'someone',
    firstName: 'some',
    lastName: 'one',
}
```

My code currently looks like this:

```
const result = await activeDirectoryUserCollection
    .findOne({username: testUser1.username});
expect(result).toBe(testUser1);
```

Obviously this gives the error that they are not equal, just because of that one value.

I'm looking for an alternative to .toBe() that doesn't completely compare the docs, but checks if one is a subset of another. (or something like that).

Alternatively I would appreciate someone to point me to a module that could help me out.

Comment: can you not just `delete result._id` and `delete testUser1._id` and then expect?

Comment: You're right, I was just making it more complex than necessary. Thank you! Also if anyone ever finds this, when comparing JSON you should use .toEqual() instead of .toBe().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would checkout Lodash module's .isMatch function.
It performs a partial deep comparison between object and source to determine if object contains equivalent property values.
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#isMatch

Example:

```
var object = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 };

_.isMatch(object, { 'b': 2 });
// => true


_.isMatch(object, { 'b': 1 });
// => false
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through one Object and use the key to assert value in both Objects. Read More [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

```
const result = await activeDirectoryUserCollection
    .findOne({username: testUser1.username});

for (const prop in testUser1) {
   if (testUser1[prop]) {
     expect(result[prop]).toBe(testUser1[prop]); // or use .toEqual
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to look outside jest for this. You can use `expect.objectContaining()`, which is described in the [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect.html#expectobjectcontainingobject) as:

> **expect.objectContaining(object)** matches any received object that recursively matches the expected properties. That is, the expected object is a subset of the received object. Therefore, it matches a received object which contains properties that are present in the expected object.

You could use it like:

```
test('objects', () => {
    expect(doc2).toEqual(
        expect.objectContaining(doc1)
    );   
  });
```